# error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11111: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor

Tags: python, opencv

i  have followed a tutorial on creating a training set to recognize a face 
here is the code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load HAAR face classifier
face_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# Load functions
def face_extractor(img):
    # Function detects faces and returns the cropped face
    # If no face detected, it returns the input image

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    if faces is ():
        return None

    # Crop all faces found
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cropped_face = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    return cropped_face

# Initialize Webcam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
count = 0

# Collect 100 samples of your face from webcam input
while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if face_extractor(frame) is not None:
        count += 1
        face = cv2.resize(face_extractor(frame), (200, 200))
        face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Save file in specified directory with unique name
        file_name_path = r'C:\Users\madhumani\path\\' + str(count) + '.jpg'
        cv2.imwrite(file_name_path, face)

        # Put count on images and display live count
        cv2.putText(face, str(count), (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0,255,0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('Face Cropper', face)

    else:
        print("Face not found")
        pass

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 13 or count == 100: #13 is the Enter Key
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()      
print("Collecting Samples Complete")
```

and whenever i tried to run this code in my jupyter notebook i have got this error

```
error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11111: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor
```

and tried to figure out the issue by searching this over stackoverflow and all other sites even after searching i couldnt understand the reason  behind this issue 
here is the commplete traceback of the error
error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-6aa561124bc3> in <module>()
     30 
     31     ret, frame = cap.read()
---> 32     if face_extractor(frame) is not None:
     33         count += 1
     34         face = cv2.resize(face_extractor(frame), (200, 200))

<ipython-input-13-6aa561124bc3> in face_extractor(img)
     11 
     12     gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
---> 13     faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
     14 
     15     if faces is ():
```

and i have tried adding 2.4.13 v dll files in the python  root directory as well as added them to the environment variable but still its of no use

Comment: The detectMutiScale function is not getting an image array. That is why the error is showing. Please check your camera is working by adding `print(type(frame))` after `re,frame=cap.read()`. Make sure that frame is not `None`

Comment: @Sreekiran i returned  a none object while i tried to print the type of frame

Comment: so now by your answer i can confirm that the camera  module isnt working in opencv please  could you tell me the possible ways to make it work  by installing any packages or adding any modules or so ??

Comment: Try using VideoCapture(1) instead of 0. 0 is usually applicable for inbuilt web cameras. Can you tell me your hardware, OS details?

Comment: os: windows 10 64bit 
hardware:
i7 8th 
8gb ram 
gt 1050 4gb graphics

Comment: is it a laptop or are you connecting the webcam externally in desktop

Comment: inbuilt web cam in laptop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187047/discussion-between-mounikes-mintu-and-sreekiran).